# MO answers that are Google top hits

Tags: discussion, searching

The question ["Who is L. A. Balashov?"](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/69440/who-is-l-a-balashov) shows the following curious behavior: Only a few minutes after posting, it became a Google top-hit for the search terms "mathematician balashov":

https://www.google.de/search?q=mathematician+balashov

This makes me curious to ask:

> Which MO questions appear on the Google frontpage?

Obviously, this question is ill-posed as you could copy a large-enough fraction of the question and paste it into Google to get back the question as top hit. I am more interested in cases where one searches for some reasonable and small collection of words and gets an MO question that asks a question which is suited to help somebody who searched for these words.

An example of a good answer would be

> topology open set

(no quotes), however, the respective MO answer is currently on place three…

An even better example is

> trace interpretation

resulting in a great MO thread as top hit.

As commented by Tobias Kildetoft, Google personalizes the search. You can omit personal results with this button [image] and you can use the "private browsing" feature to turn off personalization (apart from personalization by country/IP/"whatever Google tracks and is not blocked by private mode").

Comment: I have a feeling many of these results will be skewed if checked by users of MO, since Google customizes results to the individual.

Comment: Good point, but actually, for me the first results do not change for the examples given in the question.

Comment: It's not just about private mode. It's also about geolocation. Searching for "cambridge" in the US and in the UK will yield different results.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Sure, you may include from where you searched in your answer. It could be quite interesting to see differences in the ranks depending on the location…

Comment: I have taken the liberty to replace the lmgtfy.com link with a real Google one. I don't think this is the right place to use lmgtfy; apart from looking a bit too passive-aggressive for my taste, it adds an unjustified delay before one can see the results of the search.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni That's ok with me. I thought of this as a fun question and hence, didn't mind the lmgtfy-link (especially since it ended up at the right page). I did not mean to appear or assume either passive, aggressive or passive-aggressive behavior…

Answer (score 12):

- laid off math faculty ([1st](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/63347/what-universities-have-laid-off-tenured-math-faculty-for-financial-reasons) and [2nd](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/63221/ideas-on-how-to-prevent-a-department-from-being-shut-down) place)
- urban legends math ([1st](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/53122/mathematical-urban-legends) place)
- math jokes ([7th](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/1083/do-good-math-jokes-exist) place)
- good math videos ([2nd](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/1714/best-online-mathematics-videos) place)

For something more serious

- Hodge conjecture ([4th](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/54197/why-is-the-hodge-conjecture-so-important) place)

Some more things

- teaching Riemann integral ([1st](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/52708/why-should-one-still-teach-riemann-integration) place)
- Thompson group amenable ([1st](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/26821/is-thompsons-group-f-amenable) place)
- higher category theory ([4th](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/185997/why-higher-category-theory) place)
- Yoneda lemma ([3rd](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/3184/philosophical-meaning-of-the-yoneda-lemma) place)
- model category ([4th](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/78400/do-we-still-need-model-categories) place)
- abc conjecture ([5th](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/106560/philosophy-behind-mochizukis-work-on-the-abc-conjecture) place)
- good examples math ([4th](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/358/examples-of-great-mathematical-writing) and [5th](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/1083/do-good-math-jokes-exist) place) [Note: I wanted to make [this surface](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/4994/fundamental-examples) but instead the "jokes" question came up again.]
- memorable title ([3rd](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/44326/most-memorable-titles) place)
- wrong result math ([7th](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/35468/widely-accepted-mathematical-results-that-were-later-shown-wrong) place) Also of note 1st to 4th goes to SO, and 5th and 6th to math.se. It seems the SE network totally dominates the market for wrong math.  ;-)

Comment: Excellent! It a pleasure to see that the urban legends from MO are on first place. The math jokes make place five for me (customized) but do not hit the front page when googling non-personalized.

Answer (score 11):

- [infinite chess](https://www.google.com/search?q=infinite+chess) (6th place)
- [ZFC independence](https://www.google.com/search?q=ZFC+independence) (4th place)
- [continuum hypothesis solution](https://www.google.com/search?q=continuum+hypothesis+solution) (1st place)
- [definable numbers](https://www.google.com/search?q=definable+numbers) (4th place)
- [premium white chalk](https://www.google.com/search?q=premium+white+chalk) (1st place)
- [common false beliefs](https://www.google.com/search?q=common+false+beliefs) (4th place)
- [Turing undecidable](https://www.google.com/search?q=Turing+undecidable) (4th place)
- [compact hausdorff topology](https://www.google.com/search?q=compact+Hausdorff+topology) (3rd place)
- [Borel set](https://www.google.com/search?q=Borel+set)
- [even cardinalities](https://www.google.com/search?q=even+cardinalities)
- [universal partial order](https://www.google.com/search?q=universal+partial+order)
- [rigid relation](https://www.google.com/search?q=rigid+relation)
- [Leibnizian model](https://www.google.com/search?q=Leibnizian+model) (2nd)
- [ultrapowers](https://www.google.com/search?q=ultrapowers) (2nd)
- [V=HOD](https://www.google.com/search?q=V%3DHOD) (5th)
- [Levy collapse](https://www.google.com/search?q=Levy+collapse) (3rd)
- and many more! I found most of these quite easily.

Comment: For me even just "good chalk" without quotes gives 4th place.

Comment: Looks like the query terms themselves are personalized.  Looks like fun.  Gerhard "Maybe I'll Post Some Too" Paseman, 2015.11.09

Answer (score 2):

The search *minimal hausdorff* gives a top hit.